# string declaration before main funciton in C++

Tags: c++, syntax

i'm new to understanding stri and declaring them. can a string variable = "" ;
i'm confused why you could put a equal sign on a declaration also. is this to declare a function to be empty sort of like a global variable? like    int variable = 0;  is that sort of like a global string variable?  once i change it it'll be stored down in main function and other fucntions?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
string variable = "";
int main() {


return 0;
}
```

Comment: "why a function would be declared in this way in string?" - wat? the function is **not** declared inside the string...

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to say/ask. I'm sorry if you don't know english very well, but these sentences are not comprehensible to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement you're asking about defines a variable in
namespace scope (in this case, the global namespace).  It's more
or less like any definition: except with regards to linkage and
lifetime:

The lifetime is static, which means that the variable will be
initialized *before* `main` is entered (in practice, anyway),
and will be destructed *after* `exit` is called.

The linkage is external, which means that the name `variable`
always refers to the same entity, even in different translation
units.

And of course, since the scope is namespace scope, the variable
can be directly referred to from any function in that namespace,
or in any namespace nested in that namespace.  And since all
other namespaces are nested in the global namespace, that means
that the variable can be referred to everywhere (unless some
other declaration is hiding it).

Answer (score 0):

There are four separate parts to the small example you posted:

1) Include the necessary headers:

```
#include<iostream>
```

2) Declare any used namespaces:

```
using namespace std;
```

3) Now this is what you are probably asking about:

```
string variable = "";
```

This line above is completely independent of the function below. It is declaring a **global** variable called `variable`, of type `string`. It is also assigning a value to it, which just happens to be the **empty string** i.e. `""`. You could also have said instead:

```
string variable = "My name is numLOCK";
```

So you are just initializing the value of that variable to the specified text <strike>assigning aome value to the variable</strike>.

4) Next comes the `main` function. This does the actual work.

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can use the global variable declared above in your `main` or any other function. You can also declare more variables inside the function. For example:

```
string someText = "My name is numLOCK";

int main() {

    int someNumber = 42;

    cout << someText << endl;
    cout << someNumber << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This will print out:

```
My name is numLOCK
42
```

Comment: thank you so much guys.  i didnt' know global variables can be manipulated like this with strings.  strings are kind of more interesting.

Comment: global variable can be of any type

Comment: For what it's worth, there's no assignment in `string variable = "";`.

Comment: @JamesKanze right.. strictly speaking, this is initialization, not assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign value to a string variable in two ways.

```
string variable = "";
```

This means that you declared a variable named **variable** of type string and you assigned an empty string to this **variable**.

You can also assign value this way

```
string variable("");
```

this means exactly the same as the one above. but here you don't need the equal sign.

Here's a reference which can help you understand strings  http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html

Comment: thanks for the clear idea.  so its what people do i supposed to initialize it as empty.  its weird because ive searched a lot of spots to find this simple question

Comment: You can only _assign_ to a string in one way.  Neither of your examples have any assignment, only initialization.

Comment: @JamesKanze, oh yeah! Thank you so much for your clarification.